# How to use fopen() in PHP to write passwords to txt

Tags: php, fopen, handle

I want to have this script which receives a POST from another PHP script to append the contents (username in this case) to a file called passwords.txt which already exists in the same directory as this script. The print is there to check that the POST is successful (it is). Here's the code:

```
</html>
<body>
   <?php
      $indo=$_POST["username"];
      $handle=fopen('/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/passwords.txt',"a");
      print($_POST["username"]);
      fwrite($handle, $indo);
      fclose($handle);
   ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what's the question? ;) Also, You don't need to have php code inside html tags, php is pre-processed

Comment: Oops, the question is, why won't the fwrite work? passwords.txt is still empty. Permissions are not the issue.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag:  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Oh hell, sorry, found out that the problem was with another file. Thanks for the input guys.

Comment: @user2167980 : This question is not helpful to other users. Think about whether this should be deleted.